# How to find a phrase in a string based on a character

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, vb6

Let's say I have the following string:

sdfhahsdfu^asdhfhasdf^asd7f8asdfh^asdfhasdf^**testemail@email.com**^asdhfausdf^asodfuasdufh^alsdfhasdh

What's the best way of extracting the email from that string?  I thought of maybe split(string, "@") but then I'm not sure where to go from there.

Note: the email will always be flanked by ^ on either side, but the position in the string will be different depending on the string.

Comment: VB.net or VB6 ? Can't be both :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would split over ^ and then loop through all items to find something containing a @

```
'1 form with:
'  1 command button: name=Command1
Option Explicit

Private Sub Command1_Click()
  Dim lngItem As Long
  Dim strString As String
  Dim strItem() As String
  strString = "sdfhahsdfu^asdhfhasdf^asd7f8asdfh^asdfhasdf^testemail@email.com^asdhfausdf^asodfuasdufh^alsdfhasdh"
  strItem = Split(strString, "^")
  For lngItem = 0 To UBound(strItem)
    If InStr(strItem(lngItem), "@") > 0 Then
      DoEmail strItem(lngItem)
    End If
  Next lngItem
End Sub

Private Sub DoEmail(strEmail As String)
  Print strEmail
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use Regex to find your string. Try something like:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match("\^[^\^]+@[^\^]+\^", myString)
```